# In the .cpp, is there a way to auto-implement all the functions from its .h?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I think this would increase the quality of life when devving, but google came up with nothing and I couldn't find anything specific inside inside Netbeans either.

What I want is to start with this header:

```
class bla
{
public:
    static void gfg(somearg asd);
};
```

Then I open the blank bla.cpp and pressed 'autoimplement'. After that, it would look like this:

```
#include "bla.h"

static void bla::gfg(somearg asd)
{
    //TODO: implement
    throw unimplemented("void bla::gfg(somearg) is unimplemented");
}
```

Anyone know of a tool like this?

Comment: What do you mean, could you provide an example of what you want or be more specific?

Comment: How far back in the inheritance tree would you want to go? Classes derived from multiple, or many, base classes will cause you problems. Do you really want to create method stubs for *absolutely all* method declarations?

Comment: This is a really useful feature sometimes.  It is common in Visual Studio/Resharper, at least for .NET -- if you declare that a class implements an interface, you can have it autogenerate stubs for all public members of that interface (usually with implementations that throw a NotImplemented exception).  I would actually like this ability in other IDEs.

Comment: I believe Eclipse implements this functionality.

Comment: If nothing exists to do it for you, you could learn a little Perl (or other suitable weapon of choice) and write a script to do it with ease. Probably not the answer you are looking for but there we go

Comment: Voting to reopen. With a little bit of cleanup to clarify to what degree (inheritance wise) they wish to auto-implement, I believe this is an extremely useful question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found http://www.radwin.org/michael/projects/stubgen/

"stubgen is a C++ development tool that keeps code files in sync with their associated headers. When it finds a member function declaration in a header file that doesn't have a corresponding implementation, it creates an empty skeleton with descriptive comment headers."

This looks like it does exactly what you want it to do.

Answer (score 3):

Some time has passed and in the meantime the requested feature seems to have been implemented in netbeans. Refer to https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=213811 , which also gives a description on how to use it:

> Note:
>   Implemented CTRL+SPACE.
>   IDE suggest implementing of class method if CTRL+SPACE was pressed:
>   - inside file that already has at least one method definition
>   - between method declarations

Comment: how to use it: put your cursor on a line in a cpp file outside any existing functions and press CTRL+SPACE. Netbeans gives you a drop-down list as for normal auto-complete functionality. It seems like you need an existing cpp file and at least one method already implemented.

Comment: @craq thanks for the comment. When coming back to the question, I also noticed that the answer did rely heavily on the link to the bugtracker page. I edited the answer to include the usage description from there (although your explanation is even better, I think)